# Httpclient 4.3.6: Invalid redirect URI

Tags: java, apache-httpclient-4.x

I am using LaxRedirectStrategy in my httpclient 4.3.6 configutaion. After redirection inside DefaultRedirectStrategy class it is creating location inside createlocationURI method of DefaultRedirectStrategy class. There it is failing for this URL "/harborone0457/Profile%20-%20{0}.aspx" due to illegal character.
Any help how to solve it. Below is the logs

```
Caused by: org.apache.http.ProtocolException: Invalid redirect URI: /harborone0457/Profile%20-%20{0}.aspx
at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRedirectStrategy.createLocationURI(DefaultRedirectStrategy.java:197)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRedirectStrategy.getLocationURI(DefaultRedirectStrategy.java:145)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRedirectStrategy.getRedirect(DefaultRedirectStrategy.java:217)
at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:119)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:184)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82)
... 8 more
Caused by: java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in path at index 29: /harborone0457/Profile%20-%20{0}.aspx
at java.net.URI$Parser.fail(URI.java:2848)
at java.net.URI$Parser.checkChars(URI.java:3021)
at java.net.URI$Parser.parseHierarchical(URI.java:3105)
at java.net.URI$Parser.parse(URI.java:3063)
at java.net.URI.<init>(URI.java:588)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRedirectStrategy.createLocationURI(DefaultRedirectStrategy.java:186)
... 15 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that braces `{` and `}` needs to be encoded in order to form a valid URL:

```
  {       =       %7B
  }       =      %7D
```

Full list on URI encoding is available [here](http://www.degraeve.com/reference/urlencoding.php)

Comment: Thank you, I have made a custom function to encode these characters and it is working, it should be taken care by the apache implementation :(

Comment: @SumitKumar care to share the implementation?